# Django query date

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have 4 rows in db.

```
#Dates
Fri 18 Nov 2021
13:45 pm. - 14:45 pm.
Fri 18 Nov 2021
14:47 pm. - 15:47 pm.
Fri 18 Nov 2021
19:53 pm. - 20:11 pm.
Thu 18 Nov 2021
20:39 pm. - 21:39 pm.
```

How to perform a query in Django and get a result like below, i'm using postgresql:

```
#Dates
Fri 18 Nov 2021
13:45 pm. - 14:45 pm.
14:47 pm. - 15:47 pm.
19:53 pm. - 20:11 pm.

Thu 18 Nov 2021
20:39 pm. - 21:39 pm.
```

Let's say:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(..

#models.py
class Cast(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: are you storing date time together?

Comment: yes, as DateTimeField.

Comment: add the model in question.

Comment: I've updated the initial question.